# How to observe Gps Provider continually?

Tags: android, gps

I want to know when the GPS on the device is tuned on, and the location is changed.

Here is what I've done:

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {   
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"onlocation changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"providerdisabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"provideenabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {

    }
}
```

It is working fine when my app runs in the foreground, but when I close it, I won't get any more updates. I'd like to know how to get this information continuosly until my application is uninstalled.

Comment: that's why `Service` are existing

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203995/location-listener-as-a-service

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this in a service and start the service sticky.

Also you should think about using the FusedLocationManager by using GooglePlayServices.

For more info about GooglePlayServices and locations read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
read here for info about service - in service onCreate you just put the existing code of your activity